# WebClient DownloadFile - Access denied or could not find part of the path

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

I am trying to set a button so that the user can download a file saved on the server.

```
protected void btnDownloadHtmlFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = @"D:\web\mytestwebsite.com\www\temp\test.html";
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.Create(path);
    }

    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);
    tw.WriteLine("<head></head><body>test</body>");
    tw.Close();

    WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
    webclient.DownloadFile(@"D:\web\mytestwebsite.com\www\temp\test.html", @"C:\web\test.html");
}
```

This result in `Could not find a part of the path 'C:\web\test.html'.`
Same if I change for

```
 webclient.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://mytestwebsite.com/temp/test.html"), @"C:\web\test.html");
```

If I change for

```
webclient.DownloadFile(@"D:\web\mytestwebsite.com\www\temp\test.html", "test.html");
```

or

```
webclient.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://mytestwebsite.com/temp/test.html"), "test.html");
```

I get Access to the path 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\test.html' is denied.

Finally I went to the folder C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv to give permissions to NETWORK SERVICE but it says access denied. I am logged as a Admin on the server.

I read a few posts on this but nothing seems to work for or I missed something.

What is right way to use WebcClient.DownloadFile?

Comment: First, why you need to create file on server location and save that to server location once again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got your issue into my head. When you have used `webclient.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://mytestwebsite.com/temp/test.html"), @"C:\web\test.html");`, then make sure that you have directory `web` in `C:\`. I mean make sure you have `C:\web` in your file system. Else it will throw error. Because it needs directory to exist, so that it can just create new file.

When you did  `webclient.DownloadFile(@"D:\web\mytestwebsite.com\www\temp\test.html", "test.html");`, it tried to create file in current execution file scope i.e. `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\` and there it tried to create file, due to access permission, it is not able to create file there.

**Solution**, try to use following code, it should create file in `D:\web`.

`webclient.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://mytestwebsite.com/temp/test.html"), @"D:\web\test.html");`

**EDIT**

**Disclaimer** You are doing it wrong ( if i am not clear about requirement ), `DownloadFile` is to download an url to server location, there is now point for download a local file and saving that to again local location, it is like `save as` file to any other location.

**EDIT**

To allow end user to download file use following code.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/html";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=a.html"); // replace a.html with your filename
Response.WriteFile(@"D:\webfile\a.html"); //use your file path here.
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: Wrong usage of webclient.downloadfile - it would download the file to a local file on the server - not the client

Comment: But as per OP's requirement, it will solve the purpose, and it will download to server location, is that OP want?

Comment: They want to download a file saved on the server

Comment: If you look at OP's code, file is creating on server and again saving that to server location, did you get any point of doing that? I mean might be he needs to know `DownloadFile` usage on experimental basis.

Comment: If you look at the OP's code, they're trying to download a file from their test website and save it to the C drive - hence downloading a file to the client - DownloadFile won't do that. Why don't we let OP clarify instead of second guessing?

Comment: @ArindamNayak I have a folder C:\web. So let's say I want, as a user, to download a file from my website. Should not I see a box from the browser asking me where to save it or save it in the default folder set in the browser? Yes the file is created and save on the server as an automated thing. Then the user gets this file as a download.

Comment: @Greg, you want to achieve this -  `end user will be able to download the file from your server?`

Comment: @ArindamNayak This it it, response.writeFile. So webclient.downloadfile is not made for that purpose at all? Thanks!

Comment: @Greg, `downloadfile`  is to download an URL containing mp3 , video, html content  to your server location, you were doing it wrong.